# How do i get rid of Browse2Save hijacking

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, adware

While I was surfing the internet, suddenly firefox displaying annoying pop up ads by Browse2Save. Browse2Save ads are always showed up when I entered other sites.

I tried to remove it but can't find the program the source of Browse2Save ads. Browse2Save doesnt exist on add\remove program.

My antivirus didn't scan any suspicious on my system.

How to completely get rid of it ?

**UPDATE**

I've found [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvjOBJ8nj9c) that describe the solution, but now i cannot locate my Application Data folder. It was missing, even i unhide all folder.

Comment: Application Data is stored in all versions of Windows at: `%appdata%` however, Windows XP doesn't have `%programdata%`

Comment: Run [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) and [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/).

Comment: Im using windows xp, not 7

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all suspicious apps using control panel.

Go to Firefox - tools - addons and uninstall all suspicious addons or extensions.

If the extension comes back after restart, you'll need to delete the malware from all those folders other commenters mention.